# Octave: I cannot change the value of a global variable after clearing it

Tags: global-variables, octave, variable-declaration

I have defined a global variable `global x=-2`. Once created, global variables cannot be reassigned, i.e., `x=7` will not change the `-2` value of `x`. For this reason I clear the variable.

```
>> clear x
```

I check that the variable does not exist any more.

```
>> exist("x")
ans = 0
```

But when I create the global variable again with a new value, for example, `global x=7` I get the global variable in the old value.

```
>> global x=7
>> x
   x = -2
```

Why is this happening? Is the variable `x` not really deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is expected behaviour. It looks weird but consider the following example:

```
global x = 5;

function say_x ()
  global x = 3;
  disp (x);
endfunction

say_x ();
x = 7;
say_x ();
```

Which returns:

```
5
7
```

Note that you need declare `x` within functions to access the global variable. Also note that assigning to it the value of `3` does not work. The reason is that lines such as `persistent x = 3` or `global x = 3` are only evaluated the first time. This means that when you call `say_x()`, `x` already has a value so it never assigns to it the value of `3` (the right hand side never even gets evaluated).

Now; on to your actual issue which is all of this happening in the main/base namespace/symbol table, mixed up with what `clear()` is supposed to do. You are running this:

```
global x = 1;
clear x;
global x = 2;
x # you are surprised that x is 1 instead of 2
```

First, note that `clear()` does not actually clears the values of the variables. It will remove their names from the symbol table. Note the help text from `clear()`:

```
-- Command: clear [options] pattern ...
    Delete the names matching the given patterns from the symbol table.
```

With "normal" variables, the names won't be anywhere else and you will effectively remove their value. But that's not true with global variables. Their values will remain somewhere, ready to be made accessible the next time a global variable with their name gets defined.

What is happening when you try to define `x` again, is that the name already exists in the symbol table of global variables. So you are bringing it back to the current symbol table (just like what happens inside a function) and the right hand side (`= 2`) never gets evaluated.

As you already found, to actually remove names from the global symbol table, you need to use `clear -global` (as it is documented on the help text of `clear`).

Answer (score 1):

We need to use the option **-global** to effectively delete the global variable: `clear -global x`

**Example:**

```
>> global x=-2
>> clear -global x
>> exist("x")
ans = 0
>> global x=7
>> x
   x = 7
```

This must be a bug in Octave, because `clear` command alone *seems* to work fine clearing the global variable: no error message, and the "`exist`" check outputs the expected.

(Hope it helps, it took me some minutes to find the solution ;))

Comment: That's not a bug. You are confusing removing values are removing a name from a symbol table (`clear()` does the later). While they often are the same, that's not true for global variables.

Comment: That's a bug. I've been programming in various languages for over 30 years, I've never seen a language that just ignores you when you reset a global variable. Two hours of my life wasted figuring out what the problem was.